# Materialize CSS turn datepicker into monthpicker

Tags: html, datepicker, materialize

I need to pick a month and year as a filter.
I use materialize css over my whole webapplication. Now I encountered a problem, I want to pick a month, so html input type = month. But Materialize CSS only offers date. How can I turn my datepicker into a monthpicker?

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
```

And my html is simple, but does not give me the month, it also gives me the day.

```
<input type="month" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/e3w1fo7q/

Comment: Does not work, still have to click on a day to get the dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code**

here i set date on selecting month

```js
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true,
      format: 'mmmm',
      selectYears: false,
      buttonImageOnly: false,
      disable: [true],
      onOpen: function() {
        $(".picker__nav--prev, .picker__nav--next").remove();
      },
      onSet: function( arg ){
    var selectedMonth = parseInt(arg.highlight[1]);
    var selectedYear = arg.highlight[0];
    var selectedDate = arg.highlight[2];
    this.close();
    this.set('select', [selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDate,{ format: 'yyyy/mm/dd' }]);
    }
  });
```

```css
.picker__frame {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 565px;
}

.picker__date-display {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 330PX;
}

.picker__calendar-container {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.picker__footer {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  clear: both;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.picker__month-display {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<input type="month" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: The CSS is not getting added... also not with ! important, it stays the same, and I get errors with the arrows

Comment: can you share the errors?what css are you trying to add

Comment: .picker__nav--prev,.picker__nav--next {
    display: none;
} this css I try to add, but it is not added, arrows still visible, the error is however gone.

Comment: actually none of the css is added, but the layout is actually good, I just want to remove those arrows next to month, because they don't work or is there a way to make them work?

Comment: you can remove these arrows using css display:none,add the style in your css.i don't find a way to make them work,here onset function return value on selecting month using dropdown

Comment: Yes but the css does not work for some reason... I've added it in my css file but it does not respond

Comment: try adding display:none !important.i think it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this code,its may helpfull to to...in this code to pick day,month and year.

$("#datepicker").datepicker({changeMonth: true, maxDate: '0',changeYear: true, yearRange: '1960:2017', dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',});

Comment: this is not materializecss?